# Web config transform for 50 instances which are on single product, with out having 50 transform files

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web.config-transform

I'm new to web config transform. We are having a product which is used by 50 clients. We are moving towards automatic deployment process. So we want to use config transform for changing the connection strings, WCF service end points and few keys during deployment. But as per my R&D on google i have a solution to achieve this by maintaining 50 Transform files. Is there any process to achieve this with less number of transform files.

Please suggest how I can achieve this.

**Note:** Here I will have different connection strings, different WCF service end points for each instance.

Comment: Think we need more info on what the transform will be changing.  Depending on what that is you could have a database lookup table and pull from there the different values for each instance instead of using the web config (depending on what you want to be different between each one)

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing an opportunity to use [ASP.Net Configuration File inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: Hi @Brad, Here we are having a product which is used by 50 clients. We are moving towards automatic deployment process. So we want use config transform for changing the connection strings, WCF service end points and few keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the following ([Referenced](http://dotnetnsqlcorner.blogspot.com/2015/06/powershell-scripts-to-apply.html)) power shell script we need not to add 50 files in build under web.config and no need to commit these in build.

We can maintain these transform configs directly in Centralized server

```
function applyConfigTransformation($src,$xdt,$dst)
{
    Add-Type -Path "D:\\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"

    try 
    {
        Write-Host 'applyConfigTransformation - Called'
        Write-Host $src
        $doc = New-Object Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlTransformableDocument
        $doc.PreserveWhiteSpace = $true
        Write-Host 'applyConfigTransformation - Load Called'
        $doc.Load($src)
        Write-Host 'applyConfigTransformation - Load completed'

        $trn = New-Object Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlTransformation($xdt)

        if ($trn.Apply($doc))
        {
            Write-Host 'applyConfigTransformation - $trn.Apply called'
            $doc.Save($dst)
            Write-Output "Output file: $dst"
            Write-Host 'applyConfigTransformation - $trn.Apply completed'
        }
        else
        {
            throw "Transformation terminated with status False"
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Output $Error[0].Exception
    } 
}

$src = "D:\\web.config"
$xdt = "D:\\web1.config"
$dst = "D:\\web2.config"
applyConfigTransformation $src $xdt $dst
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider use tokenization during the release process, instead of setting any real connectionstrings, hostnames, etc during build.

For example, your *.Release.config transformation files can look like this:

```
<appSettings xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <add key="DbConnectionString" value="__ConnectionString__"/>
</appSettings>
```

And after/during deployment, you can then replace all those values with the parameters for the given environment.
With this approach you are also able to redeploy the same build to another environment, because you haven't modified the build yet.

If you are deploying with TFS, check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2018/03/19/manage-web-config-values-between-environments-in-release-management-and-tfs/) out. There is a "Replace Tokens" task.
But you can also do this with any other system.